# Get remote host Ip address QTcpServer

Tags: c++, qt, networking, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm using Qt to create TCP server using QTcpServer. Every time a client connects to server, I would like to know the remote host's IP address and port number. I tried searching documentation but couldn't find any information on this topic.

I know there should be a way, I'm just not able to figure it out. Help please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

QTcpServer won't tell you the address/port directly on an incoming connection but you can get it by getting the connected QTcpSocket from QTcpServer::nextPendingConnection() and then using QTcpSocket's peerAddress() and peerPort() methods.